# Firefox shows CSS rule as inactive but it still gets applied

Tags: css, firefox

I my website I have two conflicting CSS rules that modify the margins. One of them, which I can't change because it is a Wordpress theme, contains the rule

```
.vc_tta.vc_tta-spacing-35 .vc_tta-tab {
    margin: 18px 17px 17px 18px;
}
```

In order to override this, I had to create the following rule:

```
.vc_tta-tab.vc_active.vc_active.vc_active
{
    margin: 18px 0px;
}
```

In Firefox 57.0.4 (64-bit), the Developer Tools show the first rule as inactive (strike through) and the second (new) rule as active. Still, both get applied and I get a different result if I uncheck the "inactive" one. How can the overridden rule still get applied and how can I prevent that?

Comment: You'd have to show us an example (like a link to your website and direct us to the element in question). If it is as you say, then it's a bug in Firefox. I feel like that's a long shot, though, and it's more likely a case of misunderstanding.

Comment: show us your html too - create a snippet (do not just include a link to your website as @Adam has said) - [Something on my website doesn't work, can I just paste a link to it?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it) but my guess is having the same class three times in a selector does not really make it more specific than the first one as in effect you have still only got a 2 class selector vs a 2 class and child selector

Comment: Why not use `.vc_tta.vc_tta-spacing-35 .vc_tta-tab.vc_active { margin: 18px 0px; }`

Comment: @Pete - repeating a class name in a selector is a well known way of hacking the specificity of the selector.

Comment: @Alohci never done it - don't see the need for it, like the important rule, if you use that and it's not to override some external plugins inline code then you don't know how to do css properly

Comment: @Pete - Quite. It's a hack. For a while I thought it was pretty neat, but actually it's just a way of digging yourself into a specificity wars hole.

Comment: @pete The specificity is needed because I cannot edit the CSS of the WordPress theme itself, I can only add to it.

Comment: so why can you not add the above selector?